# MySQL works in console, but not in PHP's mysqli->query() function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this SQL, made with MySQL Workbench: http://pastebin.com/T09Actyg

When executing the code manually in the MySQL console, everything works as expected. When querying from PHP however, I get this error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; SET @OLD' at line 2`

This is essentially my PHP code:

`$sql_conn = new mysqli($conf->sql_host, $conf->sql_user, $conf->sql_pass, $conf->db_name);
$query_str = file_get_contents("setup/sql_setup.txt");
$sql_conn->query($query_str);`

I have no idea what's going on here. All help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: the content of the sql_setup.txt file is the pastebin I linked to.

Comment: can you add the content of `setup/sql_setup.txt` in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli::query` can only make one query at a time:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

You could use `mysqli::multi_query` instead:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Ahh, that would make sense. Thanks a ton!